# GORM Configure many to many with customs columns

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have these 2 models:

```golang
type Residue struct {
    ID           int
    Name         string

    Categories []*ResidueCategory `gorm:"many2many:residue_residue_categories"`
}

type ResidueCategory struct {
    ID           int
    Name         string

    Residues []*Residue `gorm:"many2many:residue_residue_categories"`
}
```

I already have the `residue_residue_categories` table. But the columns are:

- id (int)
- residueId (int, foreign key)
- residueCategoryId (int, foreign key)

And I want to do an append association like:

```golang
db.Model(&data).Association("Categories").Append(CategoriesData)
```

But SQL generate is:

```
INSERT INTO "residue_residue_categories" ("residue_id","residue_category_id") VALUES (49,4) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

As you can see, the columns' names in the insert SQL are not correct.

I've already tried to configure additional fields like:

```golang
Categories []*ResidueCategory `gorm:"many2many:residue_residue_categories;foreignkey:residueId;association_foreignkey:residueCategoryId"`
```

```golang
Residues []*Residue `gorm:"many2many:residue_residue_categories;association_foreignkey:residueId;foreignkey:residueCategoryId"`
```

But weirdly, GORM throws: `invalid foreign key: residueId` in a simple `GetById` (before the append relation). How I can configure this relation with these custom columns' names?

Comment: Please see answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766167/21985642)

Comment: I saw that, but even create a model ResidueResidueCateogory, I could not handle successfully this relation append. A similar error was throw `invalid foreign key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a small example to try to figure out your issue. First, let me share the code, then I'll walk you through all of the relevant sections of the code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Residue struct {
    ID   int
    Name string

    ResidueResidueCategories []*ResidueResidueCategory
}

type ResidueResidueCategory struct {
    ID                int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ResidueCategoryId int `gorm:"column:residueCategoryId"`
    ResidueId         int `gorm:"column:residueId"`
}

type ResidueCategory struct {
    ID   int
    Name string

    ResidueResidueCategories []*ResidueResidueCategory
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Residue{}, &ResidueCategory{}, &ResidueResidueCategory{})

    // insert into parent tables
    db.Create(&Residue{ID: 1, Name: "residue 1"})
    db.Create(&ResidueCategory{ID: 1, Name: "category 1"})

    // insert into join table
    db.Debug().Model(&Residue{ID: 1}).Association("ResidueResidueCategories").Append(&ResidueResidueCategory{ResidueCategoryId: 1, ResidueId: 1})

    // fetch data
    var joinTableRecords []ResidueResidueCategory
    if err := db.Model(&ResidueResidueCategory{}).Find(&joinTableRecords).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range joinTableRecords {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Now, let's take a closer look at each part.
The structs' definitions have been changed a quite. I've to insert the definition for the join table and override its columns names.

> Please note that I added the definition only for completeness, you can ignore it if your join table is already present in the DB.

The other change is how I insert the data into the DB. First, you've to insert the data in the parent tables (`residues` and `residue_categories`), then you can add the association within the `residue_residue_categories` join table.
I added the `Debug()` method to show you the SQL statement sent to the DB even if you run the code without attaching the debugger.

To barely focus on the logic, I hard-coded some values within the program but it should be easy to adjust to your own logic.
Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think this will not solve my problem. When you do the `Append` the generated SQL will use the wrong columns names

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've just updated my answer with the requested code. Let me know, thanks!